# jQuery Mobile don't' execute function after pageshow

Tags: json, google-maps, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have in my Phonegap app this JQM; I create a Google map and I load markers from json file.

When i launch page2, i see the first console.log (coordinates) and the last `console.log (2222222)` - The intermediate console.log that contains numberOfElements is displays only the first time. If I see the map and i return back the whole script isn't loaded.

Why?

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#page2', function () {
    var latnow = Number(localStorage.getItem("lat"));
    var lngnow = Number(localStorage.getItem("lng"));
    var coordinate = new google.maps.LatLng(latnow, lngnow);
    console.log(latnow + ' ' + lngnow);
    $('#map_canvas').gmap({
        'center': coordinate,
            'disableDefaultUI': true,
            'zoom': 5,
            'scrollwheel': false,
            'panControl': false
    });
    $('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init', function () {
        var images = "img/icon.png";
        var images2 = "img/icon2.png";

        $.getJSON('http://www.site.com/app/json.php?lat=' + latnow + '&lat=' + lngnow + '', function (data) {
            var myObject = data;
            var numberOfElements = data.markers.length;
            console.log(numberOfElements); // <- !!!!!!
            if (numberOfElements == 0) {
                alert("no result");
                $.mobile.changePage("#home");
            }
            var myObject = JSON.stringify(myObject);
            localStorage.setItem("json_near", myObject);
            $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {
                'position': coordinate,
                    'icon': images2,
                    'bounds': true
            });

            //marker da json
            $.each(data.markers, function (i, marker) {

                $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {
                    'position': new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude),
                        'draggable': false,
                        'bounds': true,
                        'icon': images

                }).click(function () {
                    $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {
                        'content': marker.content,
                            'maxWidt': 200,
                            'maxHeight': 400,
                            'autoScroll': true
                    }, this);
                });
            });
        });
    });

    map_element = document.getElementById("map_canvas");

    var mapwidth = $(window).width();
    var mapheight = $(window).height();
    $("#map_canvas").height(mapheight);
    $("#map_canvas").width(mapwidth);

    google.maps.event.trigger(map_element, 'resize');

    console.log("2222222");

});
```

Comment: I aspect every time the whole reloads of the script... and not part of it!

Comment: Are you using multi-page or multi-file template?

Comment: I using multi-page (only one file index.html)

Comment: you mean the map doesn't show when you return back to the page? try `pagebeforeshow`.

Comment: precisely, the json file is loaded only the first time; when I come back it doesn't  load.

Comment: but the first console.log and the last console.log every time are working!

Comment: are you sure that `latnow` and `lngnow` are being passed to `$.getJSON`?

Comment: yes, beacuse they are showed every time in my console.log (and the gogle maps isn't reloaded).

Comment: I don't understand the reason.

Comment: It's weird, it should work normally. try wrapping the json with a `function` and call it there. or replace getjson with $.ajax. there should be a fix

Comment: thanks for your suggest Omar

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using this plugin - http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/ , right?

I think it is not a problem of jquery mobile. The pageshow event is called as you can see from those console.log messages. 
Try to stick `console.log("xxx")` into the gmap init handler. I think this is the one which is NOT called at the second time.

Something like

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init', function () {
        console.log("xxxxxx");
        var images = "img/icon.png";
        var images2 = "img/icon2.png";
...
...
});
```

do you see xxxxxxx in the console every time you get in the page?
If not, try to find the way how to check whether the map was already initialized (second, third, fourth time, etc.) and then, call getJSON directly.